# Should I get Windows Server

Tags: windows

Small retail business running 5 computers. Thinking about getting a server to run the printers, run a pos system, run quickbooks, and do backups. My question is whether I should invest into getting a Windows server or just use a regular computer? Or is there some other way of easily doing this? My concern is that a Windows server would cost more then it would benefit. The people running the store are not very technical, so a really simple system would be preferred.

Comment: I hate to say it but SF can't handle this type of question

Answer (score 1):

I would look at [Windows Small Business Server](http://www.microsoft.com/sbs/en/us/default.aspx).

Then see if you qualify for the [Microsoft Bizspark](http://www.microsoft.com/bizspark/) program.

This also could be done with a Linux distribution though the skilled Admin required for that role and configuration if Linux is outside of your scope may be more in costs than just purchasing of the SBS from MS which is simple enough that a low level Adm1n would not have much issue configuring.

On the Point of Sale System (POS) that would be to run the back end database correct? What software does that DB use? That may be a consideration before jumping on Linux especially if it utilizes MSSQL...

Answer (score 0):

[Consider Windows Server 2008 Foundation](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/foundation.aspx)

Limitations are that you can only have 15 users, can't be a child domain or domain trusts.

Answer (score 0):

You can do almost all these things with a simple NAS device - file sharing, print sharing, backups.  You would only need a dedicated Windows server if your POS software or other apps required a server to work.  Otherwise, just get a computer to run Quickbooks, install the POS software on the register computer, and keep all the data on the NAS.